# expiry or manufactured date?

Tags: translation

does the 2018 09 01 in the following image mean the expiry date or the expiration date? Also if you can translate the other texts. Much better. If not it's ok. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

유통 기한 (and also 유통기한) means the *sell-by date*, which is usually close to the expiration date, although these two dates could differ significantly for *some* products. I have no idea how chemistry affects the ginseng. Koreans write the date in the YMD format, so it may not be safe to eat that now. Is it powder or liquid? Then, it is likely to have already gone bad.

Answer (score 3):

Assume `응용법`(How to apply) was typo of `음용법`(How to drink/eat)

How to eat : Dissolve to warm water or warm alcohol and drink at morning and evening with empty stomach

How to exchange : Store or head office (구입처 is `where to buy` literally)

Customer Service Center : 041) 753-8587

Industry-Academic Collaboration Products with Jungbu university, department of Life Science

Recommended Consumer Price : 298,000 Won

Expiration Date : Until `2018. 09. 01`

Manufactured at : Geumsan Goryeo Hongsam(Geumsan Goryeo Red Ginseng) (48-4, Ogokdong-gil, Boksu-myeon, Geumsan-gun, Chungcheongnam-do/Tel:041) 753-8587

※ Product damaged or deteriorated in distribution process can be exchanged at head office or store.

※ This product can be exchanged or compensated based on standard solution for dispute of a customer of the Fair Trade Commission.

Recycle : Tree

Recycle : Bottle(Inner package)

Answer (score 2):

유통기한 is sometimes translated expiry date.  Strictly speaking though, it is the distribution date - the "sell before" date.  [Businesses are not permitted to sell anything past this date](https://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=938494&cid=43667&categoryId=43667).  Depending on the actual product, it may be safe to eat quite a while after this date.

Sometimes you will see 제조일 on things like milk - this is the day on which it was produced.  You also might see [소비기한](https://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=938491&cid=43667&categoryId=43667), the actual expiry date, which is after the distribution date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

In credit card, the expiration date is 만료일. (Before expiration
date, we must reissue)

In food, the expiration date is 유통기한 (유통 = distribution, 기한
= deadline).

Here 유통기한 means "Do not eat this food after the date, because
this food may go bad."