# What does 까지 mean after a date ? Is the expiry date for distribution or for consumption?

Tags: grammar, translation, food

I bought 불닭떡볶이 and below the packaging is printed 2020.07.16 까지
And today it's 2020.07.17, so can I eat safely or the product is expired?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/5344/2162)

Comment: it's most likely expired but probably safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

까지 means "until" or "due". So it is expired, technically, but usually it is safe to eat it. It is the date until which the product is sold by, and for 불닭, the "used by" date is usually a week or later after the sold by date, although it is not explicitly written on the product.